# Can`t install linux on desktop ps

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I am tring to install Linux any version on one ps.

The ps is intel desktop board

Processor: Intel Atom CPU d2500 @ 1.86GHz 1.86GHz

Ram: 4gb

Current os: Windows 7 home 64-bit

Bios version: mucdt10n.86a

The problem is when i insert my boot usb (created by rufus-2.9.exe or unetbootin-windows-625.exe) go the menu option where i can choose what i want to do , memory test , install , test etc.

After that is just black screen nothing happens just stay lika that.

I try to disable and enabe UEFI (that user bios interface thing) ,but still nothing and nothing.

Try diferent file format for the USB, FAT32/NTFS some thing.

The usb is Apacer 3.0 , pls help.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] 
My problem was that linux instalations force the best resolution for monitor not for the video card, so when he try to run installation video card die becouse can`t take the high resolution of the monitor, so i change the monitor with smaller and :) TA-DA